# Change the main sound output

Tags: sound, soundcard, audio-jack

Usually I use my headphone to listen a music (using the front port one). Sometimes, I plugged out the headphone jack, if I want to listen by speaker (using the back port). Now my question is, can I change the output without unplugging my headphone jack.

Answer (score 1):

You can run  **alsamixer**  within a terminal  :
You will see various faders (master, pcm ...) or switchs .
Navigate with left/right arrows to  a switch called **automute** ,
change its value from "enable" to "disable" with up or down arrow :
Speaker should stay "on" with headphone connected.

Instead using  Alsamixer, you can install the graphical  mixer  **gnome-alsamixer** which as the same controls.

Comment: So many thanks! Just switched to Ubuntu today and had exactly this issue. Was even looking through alsamixer, but not enough